# Word to describe relationship between "infinitesimal" and "infinite"?

Tags: antonyms

Would infinitesimal and infinite just be antonyms of each other?

Comment: Numerically, they're ***reciprocals***, linguistically, yes, they are *antonyms*.

Comment: In certain ways. Infinitesimals are small but infinity is large. However, infinity is not a number in a number system, but rather a measure of the size of a set; whereas infinitesimals are numbers (real numbers in some systems). Also _infinitesimal_ is an adjective that's used as a count noun (for 'an infinitesimal amount'), but _infinity_ is a mass abstract noun, which can be countified when speaking of "multiple infinities", for instance, but that just means "multiple kinds of infinity", as with any mass noun. There are too many differences for a good opposition.